# Can we define a reverse mapping for the $\phi : Y \rightarrow C(X, Y)$, as $\phi(y) = y' $, where $y' $ is a constant map in $C(X, Y)$.

Tags: general-topology, functions, function-spaces

For a continuous map $\phi : Y \rightarrow C(X, Y)$, as $\phi(y) = y' $, where $y' $ is a constant map in $C(X, Y)$.
Can we define a reverse mapping as $\phi' : C(X, Y) \rightarrow Y$ for a metric space $Y$. If yes how can it be defined? And suppose $C(X, Y)$ is endowed with uniform topology.

Comment: The range of $\phi$ is a 'small' subset of $C(X,Y)$ so we cannot define  the inverse on the whole of $C(X,Y)$.

Comment: Then can we define a mapping from $C_d(X, Y) \rightarrow C_m(X, Y)$ is some sense?

Comment: What structure do you suppose on $Y$: a uniform space (to define the uniform topology), or a metric specifically? What do you mean by $C_d(X,Y)$ and $C_m(X,Y)$?

Comment: Could you add some motivation in the question as to why you'd want such a map to exist? Should the map $C(X,Y) \to Y$ map $\phi(y)$ back to $y$, or is that irrelevant?

Answer (score 0):

Ideas: if $X$ is a connected space and $Y$ is totally disconnected (like $Y=\Bbb Q$ or $Y=C$ the Cantor set etc.) then $C(X,Y) = \phi[Y]$, i.e. all continuous maps from $X$ to $Y$ are constant, and $\phi$ has an obious inverse that is also continuous (in most natural topologies that we could put on $C(X,Y)$).

Otherwise I don't really see a natural map $C(X,Y) \to Y$, unless in specific situations like $X$ pseudocompact and $Y$ an ordered space, where $f \to \max f[X]$ or $f \to \min f[X]$ seems natural. I think it will be continuous in the uniform topology, though I haven't checked the details.

Even more specific, if $Y=\Bbb R^n$ and $C(X,Y)$ has such a topology that the set of constant maps $\phi[Y]$ is closed in it and $C(X,Y)$ is normal, then Tietze applies to show there is a continuous extension of $\phi^{-1}: \phi[Y] \to Y$ to $C(X,Y)$.

Comment: @HennoBrndsma Let me first acknowledge the spaces: $C_d(X, Y)$ is the space $C(X, Y)$ endowed with uniform topology and $C_m(X, Y)$ is the space $C(X, Y)$ endowed with fine topology (stronger topology than uniform topology).

Comment: @MirAaliya so local base elements for $f$ of the former are $B(f,r) = \{g:\forall x: d(f(x), g(x)) < r\}$ and $Y$ must have a metric $d$, and for the latter ?

Comment: @HennoBrndsma  [cont.] Plus Since $C_d(X, Y)$ is always metrizable, then we have $C_m(X, Y)$ is submetrizable. Thus i want to know how the equivalent definition of submetrizability works for the space $C_m(X, Y)$. That is how can we draw a continuous injection from a space $C_m(X, Y)$ to a metric space? What will be that metric space ?

Comment: I don't think $C_d(X,Y)$ is metrisable? The functions aren't always bounded? The injection is just the identity to the weaker metric topology.

Comment: @HennoBrndsma For later case $B(f,r)= \{g:\forall x:d(f(x),g(x))<r(x)\}$ where $r(x) \in C^+(X)$, a positive real valued function.

Comment: @MirAaliya You want the $r(x)$ to be continuous too, as in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/26534896_Fine_topology_on_function_spaces) by McCoy, e.g. These are indeed submetrisable spaces as is mentioned there.